# how to convert slider value to CMTime?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm trying to change playback position by an UISlider.

Player is an AVplayer instant.

```
player.seek(to:CMTime(Slider.value))
```

I see this error : Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Would anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to pass the value to the wrong init of `CMTime`. The init with no argument labels takes no input arguments (`CMTime()`).  What you want to use instead is `CMTime(seconds:preferredTimescale)`.

```
player.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: Slider.value, preferredTimescale: 1))
```